# I can't create  libgdx  app on IntelliJIDEA from scratch. Project works on Eclipse 

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I have rewritten the message:
I moved okay one Java SE Eclipse project for Windows to IntelliJ IDEA. (It 
uses swing and awt) Then I tryed to move libgdx project from Eclipse. It 
works okay in Eclipse. I tryed to move this project to IntelliJIDEA on the 
same machine. Compilation is okay there. But I have runtime error:

```
  ...D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7534... 
  Exception in thread "main" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
  Creating window failed at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogl.JoglApplication....
```

Added later:
Good news!
I have created new project not from scratch, but as Eclipse project.
Everything works okay.
But how about creating from scratch?
I used the following links:
http://www.scottisheyes.com/using-je...0-libgdx-andro
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IntelliJIDEALibgdx

Different errors.
Last error was as follows.
I created myGame\Desktop\src\my_package\DesktopLauncher,
myGame\Main\src\my_package\HelloLibGDX.
Error, that HelloLibGDX class not found.

Please take a look at printscreen pics links below.
(It is impossible to place them here)

Comment: Its hard to help without all the relevant details.  Please include the complete backtrace from the runtime exception.

Comment: Good news. I created new project not from scratch, but from existing Eclipse project. All works okay! But I can't create from scratch anyway. Suppose I have two classes: DestopLauncher and HelloLibGDX.It says that class HelloLibGDX not found. I used this links:[link] http://www.scottisheyes.com/using-jetbrains-intellij-idea-10-libgdx-andro
[link]http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IntelliJIDEALibgdx
It does not work. Maybe they did not write something important?

Comment: printscreens: [link]http://www.k-ct.com/temp/1.jpg   [link]http://www.k-ct.com/temp/2.jpg  [link]http://www.k-ct.com/temp/3.jpg  BTW, no need to create libs folder for each project, it works on Eclipse and on IntelliJ if libgdx libraries are placed only in one place.

Comment: could you please update your question instead of comments. thx